# Is it right that PHP's finfo returns "application/zip" MimeType for a .docx?

Tags: php, file, mime-types

I am trying to get the real file type and for that I have come to PECL's finfo.

```
$fileName = "my.docx";
$f = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
var_dump(finfo_file($f, $fileName)); // I get "application/zip"
```

How is this right? Is this what I was supposed to get?

Comment: A word document is actually a `zip` archive - try changing the extension and you can open it normally.

Comment: on which OS you are using ??? windows or linux ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Word Microsoft Office Open XML Format Document format consists of a bunch of XML and other files stored in a zip file (unzip it and see). So yes, this is correct.

Comment: Then, what would be the right approach in order to distinguish between these ones and a real zip file? (Other than trusting the filename extension)